# Div does not wrap around form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `div` which I'm trying to fill with a background color. It contains a form. However, the div, and therefore the color, doesn't wrap around the form. How do I fix this?

```css
#signUpForEarlyAccess {
  float: right;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
.fully-centered {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: grey">
  Irrelevant div
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 text-center" id="signUpForEarlyAccess">
  <div class="fully-centered">
    <h3 contenteditable="true">Sign Up for Early Access</h3>
    <h5>Enter your email to be one of the first to try!</h5>
    <div class="form-group input-group">
      <input id="emailForm" placeholder="Please enter an email address" type="email" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign up</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02uLtz0w/)

Comment: You are required to place an example portion of the code here that shows the problem. Third party sites can change or disappear tomorrow helping no one in the future.

Comment: what is the purpose of top:50% on ''fully-centered'' div ?

Comment: using this solves the issue, just take out the other stuff .fully-centered {
  position: relative;
}

Comment: this transform: translateY(50%); is broking you.

Comment: The `top:50%` and the transform are there to vertically center the contents.

Comment: Using `translateY` will only translate that specific element and not the parent container.  Instead, try `padding-top: 50%` or `margin-top: 50%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/02uLtz0w/2/

I think you want something like this

```
#signUpForEarlyAccess {
  float: right;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  align-content:center;
  height:250px;
}
```

this height is just to show you that it is vertically centered ok ? Modify it as you wish.

Comment: That works! I'm not quite sure why, but I guess I can learn :)